# how to create calendar event in Android 10?

Tags: android

Error Message

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
    {
      "code": 403,
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "calendar",
          "message": "You need to have writer access to this calendar.",
          "reason": "requiredAccessLevel"
        }
      ],
      "message": "You need to have writer access to this calendar."
    }
```

even though I have already given below permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
```

Can any body help me , how to create calendar event in Android 10?

Other device its working fine.

Comment: Any Solution to this ?

Comment: Yes, actually it was not Android 10 issues , this is google calendar issue . you have to use google calendar API for this